# Where can I find applications created specifically for elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation, web-development, programming

Is there a place where you can see third party applications created specifically for elementary OS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two maintained resources at the moment.

1. [Made for elementary](http://madeforelementary.tumblr.com/)
2. [elementary-apps](http://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/)

The first one contains only applications that are stable or close to being stable. The second one contains those applications as well, but it also contains applications that are early in their development process.

Both of resources include only open source software as there is currently no proprietary applications made specifically for elementary OS.